# How to make session.save() or session.update() read only?

Tags: java, hibernate

How to make hibernate session.save() or session.update() read only?

I don't want to make changes to database but store its persistent states.

Comment: Is this for (integration) test purposes or for your live app?

Comment: Its on production system. I want to use liquibase to make database updates. https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki

Comment: Then you're using the **wrong** design. Don't mess with Hibernate 1st cache layer. Instead, load your data into a proper cache like ehcache or Hazelcast and do any update in that data source rather than in database.

Comment: then how to integrate with Liquibase? Could you please give simple example?

Comment: Are you aware that this plugin is for DDL and not DML, right?

Comment: Thanks Luiggi. You enlightened me. I assumed its for both.